# Filling All column of a table with specific value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, fill, autofill

I have a table and I wanted to fill a column with a specific value.

Sample table:
It includes temperature column which is empty and I want to fill all the rows of the relevant column with 4.56.

```
+------------+------------------+
|temperature |dt                |
+------------+------------------+
|            |9/15/2007 12:12:12|                  
|            |9/15/2007 12:14:16|
|            |9/15/2007 12:16:02|
|            |9/15/2007 12:18:23|
|            |9/15/2007 12:21:01|
+------------+------------------+
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------------+
|temperature |dt                |
+------------+------------------+
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:12:12|                  
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:14:16|
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:16:02|
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:18:23|
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:21:01|
+------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
update the_table
   set temperature = 4.56;
commit;
```